# Force parentheses even when calling parameterless functions in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, syntax

in VB.NET it is possible to omit parentheses when you call a parameterless function. However this can be very confusing because developers could think that a statement is accessing a property instead of a method. this could result in a performance drop if you are calling the method again and again instead of storing the result in a temp variable.

is there an option in VS2008 or a compiler option to force parentheses on statements that are calling a method?

and if so, would it be also possible that VS will insert missing parentheses automatically if you "format document" (Menu: Edit - Advanced)?

thanks, toebens

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No there is no such option in the VB.Net compiler.  Parens are optional and there is no warning or error that exist for using a lack of them.

The other reason is that VB.Net is a language which tries to be flexible and get the syntax out of the way of the user.   This type of restriction goes against this general philosophy.

Another issue to consider is that it's not a universally enforceable restriction.  VB.Net allows for late binding scenarios whenever option strict is set to off.  In these scenarios it is impossible for the VB.Net compiler to determine ahead of time if a particular call is a property, statement or not a valid call at all.

Comment: Urrg. This makes conversion to C# all the more difficult.

Comment: None of this (except for the late binding) is a real argument for why it wouldn't be possible to have a compile time option to detect this, just as with so many other things in the language that have evolved over time. And then in the late binding case this check should just be void (the compiler already knows if it is late binding and warns for it so not really hard to ignore the function check in the late binding case)