# Why am I getting Cannot Convert from Method Group to Type error with this code?

Tags: c#, vb.net, enums, vb.net-to-c#

I am trying to migrate some legacy VB.Net code to c#. I am using the Telerik Code Converter.

Here is my legacy VB.Net Code

```
Public Shared Function GetEnumIntFromString(ByVal value As String, ByVal convertTo As [Enum]) As Integer
    Dim enumValueArray() As Integer

    Try
        If value.Trim.Length > 0 Then
            enumValueArray = [Enum].GetValues(convertTo.GetType)

            For Each i As Integer In enumValueArray
                If value.ToUpper = [Enum].GetName(convertTo.GetType, i).ToUpper Then
                    Return i
                End If
            Next
        End If

        'Return Integer.MinValue
        Throw New Exception("Invalid Enum value.  Cannot convert '" & value & "' to " & convertTo.GetType.ToString)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Function
```

And here is the output from Telerik/s code converter...

```
    public static int GetEnumIntFromString(string value, Enum convertTo)
    {
        int[] enumValueArray = null;

        try
        {
            if (value.Trim.Length > 0)
            {
                enumValueArray = Enum.GetValues(convertTo.GetType);

                foreach (int i in enumValueArray)
                {
                    if (value.ToUpper == Enum.GetName(convertTo.GetType, i).ToUpper)
                    {
                        return i;
                    }
                }
            }

            //Return Integer.MinValue
            throw new Exception("Invalid Enum value.  Cannot convert '" + value + "' to " + convertTo.GetType.ToString);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    //=======================================================
    //Service provided by Telerik (www.telerik.com)
    //Conversion powered by NRefactory.
    //Twitter: @telerik
    //Facebook: facebook.com/telerik
    //=======================================================
```

I am getting the Cannot convert from 'Method Group' to 'Type' error (red squiggle line) under converetTo.GetType. I tried adding parentheses after .GetType but that just gave me another error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Aray' to 'int[]'"

The intent of the code is to provide an ENUM string value and the type of ENUM and get an integer value of the enum.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest you to stop right now using that code converter, it's missing a LOT of parenthesis:

- `value.Trim.Length` => `value.Trim().Length`
- `convertTo.GetType` => `convertTo.GetType()`
- `value.ToUpper` => `value.ToUpper()`
- `Enum.GetName(convertTo.GetType, i).ToUpper` => `Enum.GetName(convertTo.GetType(), i).ToUpper()`
- `convertTo.GetType.ToString` => `convertTo.GetType().ToString()`

However, here is an easier way to do what you want:

```
public static int GetEnumIntFromString(string value, Enum convertTo)
{
    return (int)(Enum.Parse(convertTo.GetType(), value);
}
```

Comment: It is missing parenthesis because they're missing in the VB.NET code... That's not the converter's fault. VB.NET supports calling methods without having to suffix them with `()`.

Comment: @VisualVincent I know that, I started programming in VB.NET. The converter should realize that's not valid in c# and either fail or add the missing `()`.

Comment: How? It cannot possibly know if `Trim` is a method, property, or even a field. It converts the syntax, which is why you can convert snippets referencing custom classes and other custom members without it complaining about anything.

Comment: @VisualVincent keeping a list of the classes provided by the framework? I mean, for example, you can't extend `string` to have a custom property, so if it's not in the framework leave it as is, so `string.ToUpper` is obviously not a property/field but a method.

Comment: That would require [unnecessary] parsing of the code as well. Up to this point I don't know of any converter that does that... If you know one I'd be interested to see it!

Comment: @VisualVincent If there's one, it surely isn't free haha. So what would you suggest, add the parenthesis on the VB.NET? IIRC, isn't one of the options that forces you to use parenthesis?

Comment: `isn't one of the options that forces you to use parenthesis?` - Apparently not: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1298605 -- `what would you suggest` - I suggest people learn to **always** use parenthesis when calling methods ;) (unless the language syntax disagrees). It's "uglier" without them and makes it harder to tell the members apart.