# Visual Basic lack of parenthesis for functions identification

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

Any way to have any sort of identification for the lack of parenthesis for functions with no parameters at VB?

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298605/force-parentheses-even-when-calling-parameterless-functions-in-vb-net) answer, but since it is 9 year old, i hope a solution exists now.

I am using Visual studio 2017. I have strict mode on. I have checked format settings available for Visual Studio and found no relative option. I have checked project settings as well.

Edit:
I have noticed that when i type a new function name that it does add parenthesis, could this be triggered somehow?

Comment: Anything wrong with my question?

Comment: I guess the downvoter may not be aware that questions on software tools commonly used by programmers are on-topic.

Comment: There isn't one because the language specification [dictates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/reference/language-specification/expressions#invocation-expressions) the empty parentheses are optional.

Comment: That is awfully hard shopping.  Everybody uses the tool they already have, the C# compiler.  It doesn't matter that you do it before or after the translation.  If you want to spend money then be sure to invest it in a vb.net to c# translator, it will do 99% of the job.  And doesn't care about parentheses.

Comment: With regards to what @HansPassant said, I recommend [Instant C#](https://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/product_details/vb-to-csharp-converter.html)

Comment: Just to clarify and save needless effort from people, i am not looking for a converter. I am looking to improve my existing codebase. Which means, to solve some issues with VB and in this specific case the missing parenthesis requirement of functions.

Comment: You could look into CodeRush and ReSharper in case one of them has that function.

Comment: Sadly, upon investigation of both none have been found to provide the desired functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to find what you need built into the compiler or project settings, because the optional parenthesis are build into the VB.Net language specification and the compiler will compile according to that specification. Now one thing you might want to consider is running your code through a VB.Net to C# Converter, then running that converted code through a C# to VB.Net converter. For example, consider this VB.Net code:

```
Sub Main
    Foo
End Main
```

If you run this through [Telerik's code converter](http://converter.telerik.com/), it produces this C# code:

```
public void Main()
{
    Foo();
}
```

Now if you take that C# code and convert it back into VB.Net using [Telerik's code Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/), it produces this Vb.Net code:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Foo()
End Sub
```

Notice how it added the parenthesis to the `Foo` method. This technique might work for you, if your code isn't too complex.

Comment: Sadly won't work for me, as my codebase is too big for that method, but might help someone in the future.

Comment: According to [this MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-basic-visual-basic?view=vs-2017) Visual Studio can do this using Pretty Listing command (I think it's Ctrl+K+D).

Comment: Tried to combine those together but sadly it does not trigger on formatting. Only when writing new functions.